# If a value has a covering another table, checking several more conditions

Tags: sql-server, join, case-when

I have 4 tables (with necessary columns): [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9fac5c9393599c4f7d5075347a92fed7)

I want to generate 2 columns with 0 or 1 whether the result of these conditions is fullfilled or not:

- IF an amount is transfered after credit date and from one of the (that specific customer's) sellers. (If yes, then 1 else 0) --column 1
- IF an amount is transfered after credit date and from one of the group members of (that specific customer's) sellers. (If yes, then 1 else 0) --column 2

I wrote a code like this:

```
SELECT distinct
  trn.Date_of_Transfer 
, trn.CustomerNumber
, trn.CustomerName
, trn.Credit /*Incoming transfer amount*/
, trn.SenderCustomerNumber -- Sender Customer Number
, case when fnd.CustomerNumber is not null then 1 else 0 end as 'IF_Credit_Customer'
, cus.GroupNumber as 'SenderGroupNumber'
, cus2.GroupNumber as 'CustomerGroupNumber' --Main customer, in transaction table
, case when cus.GroupNumber=cus3.GroupNumber and trn.Date_of_Transfer>=fnd.Date_of_Credit then 1 else 0 end as 'IF_Incoming_FromSeller'

FROM trnsac AS trn


LEFT JOIN Funds                 AS fnd  ON trn.CustomerNumber = fnd.CustomerNumber
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus  ON trn.SenderCustomerNumber = cus.CustomerID            
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus2 ON trn.CustomerNumber = cus2.CustomerID              
LEFT JOIN Vendors               AS ven  ON fnd.VendorId = ven.VendorId                  
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus3 ON ven.CustomerNumber = cus3.CustomerID
```

As you can see, I got wrong results for column 1 ( and not even figured out how to do column 2 ) :(

For example, Danny's second transaction is multiplying and column 1 value is different in both (same) transaction. It should be 1 because 554-Hoogle Glass is not one of his vendors (however it is in same group with the one of the seller of Danny, which should be marked as "1" for column 2)

Expected result is below:

[image]

I am struggling with:

1. Getting clean and solid data with IF_Incoming_FromSeller
2. Revising the code to get result for IF_Incoming_FromSeller

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Some questions for clarification. 1. What is each row supposed to represent - one transaction? 2. If this is the case, why does your transaction table have 7 rows but your expected result 6? 3. What are the funds and what part do they play? For those who have 2 records in funds, how does it affect the results?  4. Is there a typo in the last line of funds - mismatching customer number and name?

Comment: thanks for comment. Answers: (1) for expected result: yes, each row is representing a transaction. (2) You are right :)  now i figured that i accidently deleted a row (Denise's 2k transaction) (3) Funds table is the place where all credit details are stored. It would be required to determine a account transaction is done after a credit. (4) that's a typo, i edited the link and corrected.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This answer isn't perfect but I hope it gets you over the current roadblock. You'll need to tweak the logic to fit (part of a broader review that's not covered here). However, here's the start.

My first step was to get rid of the things that caused you to get extra rows.. and I came up with this.

```
SELECT 
  trn.Date_of_Transfer 
, trn.CustomerNumber
, trn.CustomerName
, trn.Credit /*Incoming transfer amount*/
, trn.SenderCustomerNumber -- Sender Customer Number
--, case when fnd.CustomerNumber is not null then 1 else 0 end as 'IF_Credit_Customer'
, cus.GroupNumber as 'SenderGroupNumber'
, cus2.GroupNumber as 'CustomerGroupNumber' --Main customer, in transaction table
--, cus3.GroupNumber as 'Vendor_GroupNumber'
--, case when cus.GroupNumber=cus3.GroupNumber and trn.Date_of_Transfer>=fnd.Date_of_Credit then 1 else 0 end as 'IF_Incoming_FromSeller'

FROM trnsac AS trn
--LEFT JOIN Funds                 AS fnd  ON trn.CustomerNumber = fnd.CustomerNumber
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus  ON trn.SenderCustomerNumber = cus.CustomerID            
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus2 ON trn.CustomerNumber = cus2.CustomerID              
--LEFT JOIN Vendors               AS ven  ON fnd.VendorId = ven.VendorId                  
--LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus3 ON ven.CustomerNumber = cus3.CustomerID
```

The above gets you the correct number of rows, and the relevant columns that match your expected values.

The second step was to add in the group-by (and remove your 'distinct' at the top) then use the grouping to do the logic (e.g., with `MAX(CASE())` ) statements. I am not 100% for these, but they hopefully can be cleaned by you.

I also added a new LEFT JOIN - from vendors to other vendors in the same group. That allows you to get the last column.

Here is the code.

```
SELECT
  trn.Date_of_Transfer 
, trn.CustomerNumber
, trn.CustomerName
, trn.Credit
, trn.SenderCustomerNumber
, MAX(case when fnd.CustomerNumber is not null then 1 else 0 end) as 'IF_Credit_Customer'
, cus.GroupNumber as 'SenderGroupNumber'
, cus2.GroupNumber as 'CustomerGroupNumber' --Main customer, in transaction table
, MAX(cus3.GroupNumber) as 'Vendor_GroupNumber'
, MAX(case when cus.CustomerId=ven.CustomerNumber AND trn.Date_of_Transfer>=fnd.Date_of_Credit then 1 else 0 end) as 'IF_Incoming_FromSeller'
, MAX(case when cus.CustomerId=cusgrp.CustomerId AND trn.Date_of_Transfer>=fnd.Date_of_Credit then 1 else 0 end) as 'IF_Incoming_FromSellerGroup'

FROM trnsac AS trn
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus  ON trn.SenderCustomerNumber = cus.CustomerID            
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus2 ON trn.CustomerNumber = cus2.CustomerID   
LEFT JOIN Funds                 AS fnd  ON trn.CustomerNumber = fnd.CustomerNumber
LEFT JOIN Vendors               AS ven  ON fnd.VendorId = ven.VendorId                  
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cus3 ON ven.CustomerNumber = cus3.CustomerID  
LEFT JOIN Customers             AS cusgrp ON cus3.GroupNumber = cusgrp.GroupNumber

GROUP BY
  trn.Date_of_Transfer 
, trn.CustomerNumber
, trn.CustomerName
, trn.Credit
, trn.SenderCustomerNumber
, cus.GroupNumber 
, cus2.GroupNumber
```

And here's a [DB_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d983870fa7a6f4154bdef70fef6853a) with updates.

Notes

- Denise now has funds due to the updates done after original post (typo in funds).
- I think there is a logic hole with the funds and vendors. If someone adds $500 through one vendor, then $500 through another vendor, how do you know which one(s) apply for further transactions? This could put big caveats on anything that follows on from the vendors used. You could use a running total, but that goes a bit past this answer.
- Obviously.. this hopefully gives you a push along the path. Please check the logic for the IF_ fields carefully, as well as the field Vendor_GroupNumber

Comment: Query took so long time so i did seperate the MAX section into a temp table. that seems to work..